# accessing ERRORLEVEL from bash script

Tags: bash, cmd, errorlevel

I have an application that only works properly when called from a windows command prompt. Something to do with the input/output streams.

So I can call it from a bash script by passing it as an argument to cmd.

cmd /c "badapp"

This works fine - but occasionally badapp fails with network problems - and I get no feedback. Is there anyway to check the ERRORLEVEl from the bash script - or see the output from badapp on the terminal running the bash script?

Answer (score 76):

Yes, `$?` is the variable that contains the error level.

Try `echo $?` for example.

An example from Cygwin bash (I'm guessing you are using Cygwin because you are using the Windows `cmd` in your example.)

```
susam@nifty /cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/susam/Desktop
$ cmd /c "badapp"
'badapp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

susam@nifty/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/susam/Desktop
$ if [ $? -eq 0 ]
> then
>   echo "good"
> else
>   echo "bad"
> fi
bad
```

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned I was using cygwin. Are you sure this would convert a Windows ERRORLEVEL into the bash equivalent $?

Comment: Yes! Why don't you simply try it out and confirm for yourself?

Comment: thanks this does seem to work in general. The problem seems to be with "badapp" -when it fails with network problems it doesn't consistently set the errorlevel